# List with cities vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

By clicking on the button, a list with cities opens as in the screenshot.

[image]

Code template:

```
<template>
 <div class='regions-list'>
  <select name='' :value=''>
   <option :value='item.seo_name' v-for='item in region' :key='item.name'>{{ item.name }}</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</template>
```

And vue:

```
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  region: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => []
  }
 }
};
```

I like the way it works, but it's impossible to style, and i have no idea how i can add `:value` to `select` (item.seo_name)

How can I change the code to style it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pretty close to having everything setup, and it looks good! I'm not sure about styles not working that might have something to do with child/parent issues... could be anything. Do you have a `<style></style>` block in your Vue template? As far as the value selection, I think you might be looking for something like this?

```
<select ref="dropbox" @mousedown="dropboxSelectorClicked($event)"
    @change="dropboxItemChanged($event)" >
  <option v-for='item in region' :key="item.name"  
    :value="item" 
    :selected="item.selected">
    {{ item.name }} 
  </option>
</select>

methods: {
  dropboxItemChanged: function(event){
    var selectBox = this.$refs.dropbox;
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[event.target.selectedIndex]._value;
  },
},
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but ```option``` impossible to styling, as i know :c